# How do I fix the error Headers- readonly response started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I am trying to implement JWT into my application like someone suggested. Its an ASP.NET 6 web app. Im using the default Identity setup with the razor pages for the login and register routes.

my steps:

1. updated my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Secret").Value);
    jwt.SaveToken = true;
    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtConfig:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtConfig:Issuer"],
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true
    };
});
```

2. created a JWTService class

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace TheGospelMission.Services;
public class JwtService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public JwtService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public JwtSecurityToken GenerateJwtToken(string username, string[] roles)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        };

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JwtConfig:Issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JwtConfig:Audience"],
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JwtConfig:DurationInMinutes"])),
            signingCredentials: credentials
        );
        //return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return token;

    }


 
}
```

3. modified OnPostAsync in login.cshtml.cs

```
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Action("dashboard", "Home");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Username);
                    var userRoles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                    // Use the JwtService to generate a token
                    var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Input.Username),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    };

                    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                    {
                        authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                    }

                    // Use the JwtService to generate a token
                    var token = _jwtService.GenerateJwtToken(Input.Username, userRoles.ToArray());

                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

                    var expiration = token.ValidTo;

                    // Set the JWT token in a cookie (for example)
                    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                    {
                        HttpOnly = true,
                        Expires = expiration, // Set the cookie expiration to match the JWT token's expiration
                    };

                    Response.Cookies.Append("AuthToken", tokenString, cookieOptions);


                    return Page();

                    // return new JsonResult(new
                    // {
                    //     token = tokenString,
                    //     expiration = expiration,
                    //     returnUrl = returnUrl // Include the returnUrl in the response if needed
                    // });
                }

                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    // Handle two-factor authentication as needed
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    // Handle account lockout as needed
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Unauthorized(); // Return Unauthorized in case of a failed login
                }
            }


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Results:
after doing all of this the error I keep getting on my global exception handler is:

`{System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started.`

Comment: Have you checked which line cause this error? I create a demo to mock your code and everything works fine, My browser create cookie to save the token successfully. I also confused after `Response.Cookies.Append(xxx)`, Why you just return page instead of redirecting to another page? It meaningless to return login page after user log in successfully.

Comment: ok once i removed the [Authorize] from my dashboard route the page loaded but not fully, which is wierd.  Then when i add the [Authorize] back on top i get a 401. I also committed out the Response.Cookies.Append(xxx) so i still super lost at why this is happening and where to look.

Comment: When you wanna use JWT token in your demo, You need to add this token in your request header, I am not sure if you do this.

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand what you are suggesting as i am new to this